# Instagram pushing pinned bar on scroll effect in Framer

Tags: instagram, framerjs, pinned-header-list-view

I'm a designer and Framer noob trying to accomplish the following:

Similar to Instagram, I'd like to pin the header bars of modules in a scroll container and have the next module header bar push up the already pinned header bar as you scroll down.

I can easily accomplish this in Pixate where the pinned bars move at the same rate as the scroll content and stick to the top at a specified coordinate and then continue scrolling at another, but the coordinates have to be specified for each bar - the end of one is the beginning of the next.

The bars are all the same height - is there a cleaner way to do this in Framer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey @kazzyt , any thoughts on this? You seem to be pretty knowledgeable. Even a nudge in the general direction of how this can be accomplished would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This module seems to do what you want:

https://github.com/72/StickyHeaders-for-Framer

Check out one of the demos here:

http://share.framerjs.com/4jr3dyd44bpm/